# Making meme coin on polygon network. Swap failure for no apparent reason

Tags: solidity, remix, polygon, uniswapv3

I'm working on developing a meme coin and I'm going through the testing phase to make sure everything works as intended. I am able to deploy the token and provide single sided liquidity to the pool using the smart contract. I am testing swap functionality on 3 separate accounts. There are 2 cases.

**Case 1**: Burn and Taxation Enabled

**Case 2**: Burn and Taxation Disabled

**Account 1**: X (used to deploy token)

**Account 2**: Y (used to collect taxes)

**Account 3**: Z (clean account used for nothing)

**Case 1** - When I go to uniswap V3 to swap from MATIC to MyToken, I am able to complete the swap on all accounts, but when trying to switch back to MATIC from MyToken, none work.

**Case 2** - When I go to uniswap V3 to swap from MATIC to MyToken, I am able to complete the swap on all accounts, but when trying to switch back to MATIC from MyToken, only one account will work. The account that works seems to be the first account I try the swap on, then the other two say "transaction failed" after I successfully approve the swap.

The main smart contract code is below.

```
  // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.8.18;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
// import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Burnable.sol";

interface INonfungiblePositionManager {
    struct MintParams {
        address token0;
        address token1;
        uint24 fee;
        int24 tickLower;
        int24 tickUpper;
        uint256 amount0Desired;
        uint256 amount1Desired;
        uint256 amount0Min;
        uint256 amount1Min;
        address recipient;
        uint256 deadline;
    }
    function mint(MintParams calldata params) external payable returns (
        uint256 tokenId,
        uint128 liquidity,
        uint256 amount0,
        uint256 amount1
    );
    function createAndInitializePoolIfNecessary(
        address token0,
        address token1,
        uint24 fee,
        uint160 sqrtPriceX96
    ) external payable returns (address pool);
}

// contract MyToken is ERC20, ERC20Burnable{
contract MyToken is ERC20{
    INonfungiblePositionManager posMan = INonfungiblePositionManager(0xC36442b4a4522E871399CD717aBDD847Ab11FE88);
    //address constant weth = 0xaa25Aa7a19f9c426E07dee59b12f944f4d9f1DD3; //bnb testnet
    address constant weth = 0x9c3C9283D3e44854697Cd22D3Faa240Cfb032889; // polygon mumbai testnet
    //address constant weth = 0x0d500B1d8E8eF31E21C99d1Db9A6444d3ADf1270; // Polygon wMatic
    uint supply = (900_000_000 * 10 ** decimals());
    uint reserveTokens = (100_000_000 * 10 ** decimals());
    uint256 airdropTokens = (31_000_000 * 10 ** decimals());
    uint24 constant fee = 500;
    uint160 constant sqrtPriceX96 = 79228162514264337593543950336; // 1 matic per token
    //uint160 constant sqrtPriceX96 = 2081153573722230073869968658;// 0.00069 matic per token
    int24 minTick;
    int24 maxTick;
    address public pool;
    address token0;
    address token1;
    uint amount0Desired;
    uint amount1Desired;
    address reserveAddress = 0x0f1eb866A2A63Bf316634D8dF302A7427818F2d5;
    // address taxAddress = 0x2d2117C5c971da0265E9857838f781D682158C84;
    // address[] airdropAddresses = [0x2d2117C5c971da0265E9857838f781D682158C84, 
    // 0x1fb207A17DBd7510F098781Fa78b1f02471fb272];

    constructor() ERC20("MyToken", "MYT") {
        _mint(address(this), supply);
        _mint(reserveAddress, reserveTokens); //hold 6.9% of supply as reserve
        fixOrdering();
        pool = posMan.createAndInitializePoolIfNecessary(token0, token1, fee, sqrtPriceX96);
    }

    function addLiquidity() public {
        IERC20(address(this)).approve(address(posMan), supply);
        posMan.mint(INonfungiblePositionManager.MintParams({
            token0: token0,
            token1: token1,
            fee: fee,
            tickLower: minTick,
            tickUpper: maxTick,
            amount0Desired: amount0Desired,
            amount1Desired: amount1Desired,
            amount0Min: 0,
            amount1Min: 0,
            recipient: address(this),
            deadline: block.timestamp + 1200
        }));
    }

    function fixOrdering() private {
        if (address(this) < weth) {
            token0 = address(this);
            token1 = weth;
            amount0Desired = supply;
            amount1Desired = 0;
            minTick = 0;
            maxTick = 887270;
        } else {
            token0 = weth;
            token1 = address(this);
            amount0Desired = 0;
            amount1Desired = supply;
            minTick = -887270;
            maxTick = 0;
        }
    }

    // function airdrop() public {
    //     uint256 perAddress = airdropTokens / airdropAddresses.length; 
    //     for(uint256 i; i < airdropAddresses.length; i++) {
    //         _transfer(reserveAddress, airdropAddresses[i], perAddress);
    //     }
    // }
}
```

The ERC20.Sol file is below. It has been modified slightly.

````
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
// OpenZeppelin Contracts (last updated v5.0.0) (token/ERC20/ERC20.sol)

pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import {IERC20} from "./IERC20.sol";
import {IERC20Metadata} from "./extensions/IERC20Metadata.sol";
import {Context} from "../../utils/Context.sol";
import {IERC20Errors} from "../../interfaces/draft-IERC6093.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol"; 
import "hardhat/console.sol";

using SafeMath for uint256;

/**
 * @dev Implementation of the {IERC20} interface.
 *
 * This implementation is agnostic to the way tokens are created. This means
 * that a supply mechanism has to be added in a derived contract using {_mint}.
 *
 * TIP: For a detailed writeup see our guide
 * https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/how-to-implement-erc20-supply-mechanisms/226[How
 * to implement supply mechanisms].
 *
 * The default value of {decimals} is 18. To change this, you should override
 * this function so it returns a different value.
 *
 * We have followed general OpenZeppelin Contracts guidelines: functions revert
 * instead returning `false` on failure. This behavior is nonetheless
 * conventional and does not conflict with the expectations of ERC20
 * applications.
 *
 * Additionally, an {Approval} event is emitted on calls to {transferFrom}.
 * This allows applications to reconstruct the allowance for all accounts just
 * by listening to said events. Other implementations of the EIP may not emit
 * these events, as it isn't required by the specification.
 */
abstract contract ERC20 is Context, IERC20, IERC20Metadata, IERC20Errors {
    mapping(address account => uint256) private _balances;

    mapping(address account => mapping(address spender => uint256)) private _allowances;

    uint256 private _totalSupply;

    string private _name;
    string private _symbol;

    /**
     * @dev Sets the values for {name} and {symbol}.
     *
     * All two of these values are immutable: they can only be set once during
     * construction.
     */
    constructor(string memory name_, string memory symbol_) {
        _name = name_;
        _symbol = symbol_;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the name of the token.
     */
    function name() public view virtual returns (string memory) {
        return _name;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the symbol of the token, usually a shorter version of the
     * name.
     */
    function symbol() public view virtual returns (string memory) {
        return _symbol;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the number of decimals used to get its user representation.
     * For example, if `decimals` equals `2`, a balance of `505` tokens should
     * be displayed to a user as `5.05` (`505 / 10 ** 2`).
     *
     * Tokens usually opt for a value of 18, imitating the relationship between
     * Ether and Wei. This is the default value returned by this function, unless
     * it's overridden.
     *
     * NOTE: This information is only used for _display_ purposes: it in
     * no way affects any of the arithmetic of the contract, including
     * {IERC20-balanceOf} and {IERC20-transfer}.
     */
    function decimals() public view virtual returns (uint8) {
        return 18;
    }

    /**
     * @dev See {IERC20-totalSupply}.
     */
    function totalSupply() public view virtual returns (uint256) {
        return _totalSupply;
    }

    /**
     * @dev See {IERC20-balanceOf}.
     */
    function balanceOf(address account) public view virtual returns (uint256) {
        return _balances[account];
    }

    /**
     * @dev See {IERC20-transfer}.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - `to` cannot be the zero address.
     * - the caller must have a balance of at least `value`.
     */
    function transfer(address to, uint256 value) public virtual returns (bool) {
        address owner = _msgSender();
        uint256 sellTax = 15;
        uint256 buyTax = 10;
        if (to == address(this)) {
            _transfer(owner, address(0x2d2117C5c971da0265E9857838f781D682158C84), value*(sellTax/100));
            _transfer(owner, to, value*(1 - sellTax/100));
        }
        else {
            _transfer(owner, address(0x2d2117C5c971da0265E9857838f781D682158C84), value * (buyTax/100));
            _transfer(owner, to, value * (1 - buyTax/100));
        }
        //_transfer(owner, to, value);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @dev See {IERC20-allowance}.
     */
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view virtual returns (uint256) {
        return _allowances[owner][spender];
    }

    /**
     * @dev See {IERC20-approve}.
     *
     * NOTE: If `value` is the maximum `uint256`, the allowance is not updated on
     * `transferFrom`. This is semantically equivalent to an infinite approval.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - `spender` cannot be the zero address.
     */
    function approve(address spender, uint256 value) public virtual returns (bool) {
        address owner = _msgSender();
        _approve(owner, spender, value);
        return true;
    }


    // Set tax for buys and sells
    // function setTax(uint256 sellFee, uint256 buyFee) external{
    //     sellTax = sellFee;
    //     buyTax = buyFee;
    // }

    /**
     * @dev See {IERC20-transferFrom}.
     *
     * Emits an {Approval} event indicating the updated allowance. This is not
     * required by the EIP. See the note at the beginning of {ERC20}.
     *
     * NOTE: Does not update the allowance if the current allowance
     * is the maximum `uint256`.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - `from` and `to` cannot be the zero address.
     * - `from` must have a balance of at least `value`.
     * - the caller must have allowance for ``from``'s tokens of at least
     * `value`.
     */
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value) public virtual returns (bool) {
        address spender = _msgSender();
        _spendAllowance(from, spender, value);
        // uint256 fee;

        // if ( from == address(this) ) {
        //     fee = (value.mul(buyTax)).div(10000);
        // }
        // else {
        //     fee = (value.mul(sellTax)).div(10000);
        // }

        // uint256 total = value.sub(fee);
        _transfer(from, to, value);
        //_transfer(from, address(0x2d2117C5c971da0265E9857838f781D682158C84), total);
        return true;
    }


    /**
     * @dev Moves a `value` amount of tokens from `from` to `to`.
     *
     * This internal function is equivalent to {transfer}, and can be used to
     * e.g. implement automatic token fees, slashing mechanisms, etc.
     *
     * Emits a {Transfer} event.
     *
     * NOTE: This function is not virtual, {_update} should be overridden instead.
     */
    // event Log(uint256 vSellTaxDummy, uint256 vBuyTaxDummy, address thisAddy);
    function _transfer(address from, address to, uint256 value) internal {
        // uint256 sellTax = 15;
        // uint256 buyTax = 5;
        // uint256 burnTax = 2;
        // uint256 percent = 100;
        // //address reserveAddress = 0x0f1eb866A2A63Bf316634D8dF302A7427818F2d5;

        // uint256 valueBuyTax = value.div(percent.div(buyTax));
        // uint256 valueSellTax = value.div(percent.div(sellTax));
        // uint256 valueBurnTax = value.div(percent.div(burnTax));

        // uint256 valueBuy = value.sub(valueBuyTax).sub(valueBurnTax);
        // uint256 valueSell = value.sub(valueSellTax).sub(valueBurnTax);

        // emit Log(valueBuy, valueSell, address(this));

        if (from == address(0)) {
            revert ERC20InvalidSender(address(0));
        }
        if (to == address(0)) {
            revert ERC20InvalidReceiver(address(0));
        }

        // if (from != address(this)) {
        //     if (to == address(this)) {
        //         _update(from, address(0x2d2117C5c971da0265E9857838f781D682158C84), valueSellTax);
        //         _update(from, to, valueSell);
        //         _burn(from, valueBurnTax);
        //     }
        //     else {
        //         _update(from, address(0x2d2117C5c971da0265E9857838f781D682158C84), valueBuyTax);
        //         _update(from, to, valueBuy);
        //         _burn(from, valueBurnTax);
        //     }
        // }
        // else {
        //     _update(from, to, value);
        // }
        _update(from, to, value);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Transfers a `value` amount of tokens from `from` to `to`, or alternatively mints (or burns) if `from`
     * (or `to`) is the zero address. All customizations to transfers, mints, and burns should be done by overriding
     * this function.
     *
     * Emits a {Transfer} event.
     */
    function _update(address from, address to, uint256 value) internal virtual {
        if (from == address(0)) {
            // Overflow check required: The rest of the code assumes that totalSupply never overflows
            _totalSupply += value;
        } else {
            uint256 fromBalance = _balances[from];
            if (fromBalance < value) {
                revert ERC20InsufficientBalance(from, fromBalance, value);
            }
            unchecked {
                // Overflow not possible: value <= fromBalance <= totalSupply.
                _balances[from] = fromBalance - value;
            }
        }

        if (to == address(0)) {
            unchecked {
                // Overflow not possible: value <= totalSupply or value <= fromBalance <= totalSupply.
                _totalSupply -= value;
            }
        } else {
            unchecked {
                // Overflow not possible: balance + value is at most totalSupply, which we know fits into a uint256.
                _balances[to] += value;
            }
        }

        emit Transfer(from, to, value);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Creates a `value` amount of tokens and assigns them to `account`, by transferring it from address(0).
     * Relies on the `_update` mechanism
     *
     * Emits a {Transfer} event with `from` set to the zero address.
     *
     * NOTE: This function is not virtual, {_update} should be overridden instead.
     */
    function _mint(address account, uint256 value) internal {
        if (account == address(0)) {
            revert ERC20InvalidReceiver(address(0));
        }
        _update(address(0), account, value);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Destroys a `value` amount of tokens from `account`, lowering the total supply.
     * Relies on the `_update` mechanism.
     *
     * Emits a {Transfer} event with `to` set to the zero address.
     *
     * NOTE: This function is not virtual, {_update} should be overridden instead
     */
    function _burn(address account, uint256 value) internal {
        if (account == address(0)) {
            revert ERC20InvalidSender(address(0));
        }
        _update(account, address(0), value);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Sets `value` as the allowance of `spender` over the `owner` s tokens.
     *
     * This internal function is equivalent to `approve`, and can be used to
     * e.g. set automatic allowances for certain subsystems, etc.
     *
     * Emits an {Approval} event.
     *
     * Requirements:
     *
     * - `owner` cannot be the zero address.
     * - `spender` cannot be the zero address.
     *
     * Overrides to this logic should be done to the variant with an additional `bool emitEvent` argument.
     */
    function _approve(address owner, address spender, uint256 value) internal {
        _approve(owner, spender, value, true);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Variant of {_approve} with an optional flag to enable or disable the {Approval} event.
     *
     * By default (when calling {_approve}) the flag is set to true. On the other hand, approval changes made by
     * `_spendAllowance` during the `transferFrom` operation set the flag to false. This saves gas by not emitting any
     * `Approval` event during `transferFrom` operations.
     *
     * Anyone who wishes to continue emitting `Approval` events on the`transferFrom` operation can force the flag to
     * true using the following override:
     * ```
     * function _approve(address owner, address spender, uint256 value, bool) internal virtual override {
     *     super._approve(owner, spender, value, true);
     * }
     * ```
     *
     * Requirements are the same as {_approve}.
     */
    function _approve(address owner, address spender, uint256 value, bool emitEvent) internal virtual {
        if (owner == address(0)) {
            revert ERC20InvalidApprover(address(0));
        }
        if (spender == address(0)) {
            revert ERC20InvalidSpender(address(0));
        }
        _allowances[owner][spender] = value;
        if (emitEvent) {
            emit Approval(owner, spender, value);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @dev Updates `owner` s allowance for `spender` based on spent `value`.
     *
     * Does not update the allowance value in case of infinite allowance.
     * Revert if not enough allowance is available.
     *
     * Does not emit an {Approval} event.
     */
    function _spendAllowance(address owner, address spender, uint256 value) internal virtual {
        uint256 currentAllowance = allowance(owner, spender);
        if (currentAllowance != type(uint256).max) {
            if (currentAllowance < value) {
                revert ERC20InsufficientAllowance(spender, currentAllowance, value);
            }
            unchecked {
                _approve(owner, spender, currentAllowance - value, false);
            }
        }
    }
}
````

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Hi! Could you explain how you're initializing the pool and providing liquidity?